# Get Rid Of FULL Scan Inner Query Mysql DB

Tags: jquery, mysql, database

I'm running an SQL query on MYSQL, I was expecting to access the record in one attempt.
Because the inner query gets only 1 row, this record can be accessed on a Primary key index user_id of the inactive_users_6months.
But the engine prefers FUll Scann somehow. I also used the force Index but did not solve the full scanning.
Basically, `select * from inactive_users_6months user_id IN ('XX','YY')`, returns the results but. If there is an inner query, it somehow triggers the Full Scan.
Do you have an idea how to optimize it?

```
explain select * 
from inactive_users_6months 
where user_id IN(
    select jid 
    from tig_pubsub_subscriptions 
    where node_id=6433274);
```

[image]

**explain inactive_users_6months;**
[image]

**explain tig_pubsub_subscriptions**
[image]

```
select jid from tig_pubsub_subscriptions where node_id=6433274
```

[image]

```
explain select * 
from inactive_users_6months A 
LEFT JOIN tig_pubsub_subscriptions B ON  A.user_id = B.jid
Where B.node_id=6433274;
```

[image]

```
explain select * 
from inactive_users_6months A 
INNER JOIN tig_pubsub_subscriptions B ON  A.user_id = B.jid
Where B.node_id=6433274;
```

[image]

Comment: Use `JOIN` instead of `WHERE user_id IN`

Comment: JOIN query also gives Full Scan, please look at the updated question above

Comment: I don’t understand you question. Of course MySQL is searching the whole inactive user table because it has no index

Comment: Don't use `LEFT JOIN` when `INNER JOIN` will work.

Comment: @Thallius `inactive_users_6months` has primary key = `user_id`.

Comment: @Barmar ,I've added INNER JOIN explanation , it also gives Full Scan

Comment: Can you add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table instead of the `EXPLAIN tablename` output? It's hard to see exactly how all the indexes are set up.

Comment: @Thallius user_İd is primary key , builtin INDEX we have, I can directly query by giving actual user_id (where user_id='SDSAdas'), it justs gives the result without Full Scan

Comment: Are you sure both table/columns have same charactersets and collation?

Comment: yes both (A->user_id and B->JID) are varchar(100)

Comment: "Using where; Using join buffer" Does it course Full Scan somehow?

Comment: I can't tell by the information provided, but it's not clear if the `jid` column is indexed or not, or if there may be a foreign key involved? If there is no foreign key, then I'd at least add an index on the `jid` column, and the check the query again.

Comment: @PaulT. there is no foreign key, and no need to add an index on jid. But I did try so did not change  anything.

Comment: I do not mean the column type but the charset and collation. If table one column user_id has collation UTF8_general_ci and user_id on table two has collate UTF8mb4_bin (or any other diffrent types) mySQL cannot use the key

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using EXISTS? (and not using "select *")

```
explain select t.id -- choose whatever is the pk of that table
from inactive_users_6months as t
where exists (
   select null
   from tig_pubsub_subscriptions as s
   where s.node_id=6433274             --<< this might cause the full scan
   and s.jid = t.user_id
   )
```

If that also produces a full scan try it without the s.node filter

```
explain select t.id 
from inactive_users_6months as t
where exists (
   select null
   from tig_pubsub_subscriptions as s
   where s.jid = t.user_id
   )
```

If the variability of tig_pubsub_subscriptions.node_id is high then an index on that column might help solve the full scan; but if the variability is low the optimiser may decide it is easier to do that full scan.

---

**ps** It is possible to provide explain plans in text, then those of us who are unable to see any images on this site could contribute without having to jump through hoops.

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----+-------------+
```

see Site Help article: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)    which implores you to not use images.

*(Why can I not see any images? because the image site is blocked by network admins, but there are many possible reasons, i'm not the only one so affected)*

Comment: Exists does not work

Comment: I assume it does in fact "work" - but you mean it didn't solve your full scan issue. Did you use an index on `tig_pubsub_subscriptions.node_id`?  If that index doesn't help then perhaps an index on   `node_id  and jid` or the reverse order. Note we have no clues on the cardinality of any of these columns so you may have to do some experimentation.